# How to remove brace matching border

Tags: visual-studio-2013

How can I remove unwanted border around the matching braces in Visual Studio 2013?

Update:
By "border" I mean the little border which surrounds green rectangles. VS2012 doesn't create it, VS2013 creates it.

**Visual Studio 2012 behavior:**

[image]

**Visual Studio 2013 behavior:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> **Brace Matching (Rectangle)** and **Brace Matching (Highlight)**, set the item foreground and Item background the same colors for both.

If you have ReSharper it's **ReSharper Brace Outline** and **ReSharper Matched Brace**, set the Item foreground and Item Background the same for both.